# DateListPlot and PlotLegends make FrameTicks disappear

Tags: notebooks, legending, date-and-time

I am using Mma12.0 (`$Version` gives "12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)").

Consider the procedures below:

1. Open a new notebook.
2. Type this code and run: `DateListPlot[{{{2023, 1, 1}, 1}, {{2023, 1, 3}, 2} }, PlotLegends -> Placed[LineLegend[{"JSDFJFNDF"}], Below]]`. Everyting is right until now.
3. Save and close the notebook
4. Reopen the above notebook, it warns me "unsafe dynamic content". Enable Dynamic and the FrameTicks of my plot is gone.

[image]

Note:

1. If the image is not on the screen when I close/reopen the notebook, then it will work fine and no bug appear. That is why I say "Open a new notebook" in step 1 above. If I type some random text to squeeze the image out of screen, then this problem will not be triggered.
2. It is possible related to [Why is plot legend unsafe?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/48291/why-is-plot-legend-unsafe)
3. Help! Is there easy solution to bypass this problem? I am writing a presentation, it is real annoying that the PlotLegends betrays me.

Comment: No such behavior on v12.2.0 on Win7-x64. Please include the output of `$Version` to your post. Also you are missing a `]` at the end of the code you've posted.

Comment: $Version gives "12.0.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit)", now added in the post.